# How to change to order of the store view

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to know the way to change to sort order of each store view in order to change the order when display the storeswticher in the website.
I now have **eStore | MainPage | Outlet**, I want to modify it to **MainPage | eStore | Outlet.**

I tried to change the config under the system > magento stores > store view name > sort order, but it doesn't seem like it's working

Comment: did u clear the cache after modifying the sort order??(both the browser cache and magento cache)

Comment: Logout once and clear all cache and sessions then login and try..

Comment: i tried, but the order doesn't change at all. Should i provide some more detail?